# crystal report - repeat group header across multiple column

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a report that has 3 columns and it is grouped by a value that i display in the group header.  The report is setup to run down then across.

If the details span across multiple columns, how do I repeat that group header on the next column.

I have already checked "repeat group header on each page" in the group expert.
I have already checked "format groups with multiple column" in the Layout tab of the details section.
It will not let me insert a text object in the group header of each column.

Not sure how to do this.  I could write a formula to only show at the top of each column, but not sure if there is a function to find out when the second column has started.

**edit**

What i want is below

```
 Group Header Text       Group Header Text    Group Header Text
  Detail Values            Detail Values         Detail Values
  Detail Values            Detail Values         Detail Values
```

I would like to have the Group Header Text show at the top of each column.  Doesn't matter if its the start of a new group or in the middle of the group.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I have your solution, the field, that you are grouping by , just place it on to the page header and it will repeat itself on every page until the columns of that group are finished.

Lets say you are grouping by Employee Names, just put the Employee Name field on to the page header and it should solve the issue, I jsut tried it and it worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is `Previous()` function available in formulas that allows to show-hide a Text Object based on the change of specific field value from previous to current record.

Is this what are you looking for? Can you edit you question drawing a sample af what you have and what you want?